# Android webview an internal error has occurred (TypeError) gwt

Tags: android, gwt, webview

I built an android app that gives two choices, to open a special webpage inside a web view or through browser. The webpage containing java script and ajax, return a list of items.

There is no problem when the webpage is opened through browser but when trying to open the webpage through a `webview`, it return list of items but when I click on one of them it return an error message

`an internal error has occurred
(TypeError) __gwt$exception:<skipped>:cannot call method 'setItem' of null`

Here is my code

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        WebView web = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
        Button  browser = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Browser);
        WebSettings webSettings = web.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        web.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

        web.loadUrl("http://10.45.18.22:8080/feeds-portlet/List.jsp?a=xy@gmail.com");
        final Intent i =  new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://10.45.18.22:8080/feeds-portlet/List.jsp?a=xy@gmail.com"));

        browser.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

public void onClick(View v){

       startActivity(i);
        }
        });
    }
```

I have already enabled javascript in the webview !